# WordPress WP QUERY with OR condition

Tags: wordpress

On my website, there are a couple of custom post types with default blog posts. On the blog posts, there are many categories.

One of the post types is `webinar`. I like to query all posts from the post type `webinar` and those blog posts that have category id `43`

I tried following way but does not work.

1:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => array('webinar'), // I need all post from webinar
  'cat' => '43', // I need all blog post under this category (Post type post category id 43)
);
```

Result: No post found

2:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => array('webinar','post'), // I need all post from webinar
  'cat' => '43', // I need all blog post under this category (Post type post category id 43)
);
```

Result: Only posts of category id 43, no post from post types `webinar`

I need something like the following:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'post_type' => array('webinar')
    ),
    array(
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'cat' => '43'
    )
  )
));
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

```
// This could be cached in the site option
// in case this code will take a long time.
$webinar_terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => '{webinar_tax_name}',
    'hide_empty' => true,
]);

$allowed_terms_ids = [];

foreach ( $webinar_terms as $term )
{
    $allowed_terms_ids[] = $term->term_id;
}

// Add post cat to allowed terms.
$allowed_terms_ids[] = 43;

$query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => ['webinar','post'],
  'cat' => $allowed_terms_ids,
]);
```

**NOTE**

This will work only in case all `webinar` posts will be assigned to at least 1 `{webinar_tax_name}` term.

**Solution 2**

You may use `posts_request` hook and update SQL for 1 of your queries in your example. But I would prefer 1st solution as it will be more clear for other devs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = get_posts([
  'post_type' => 'webinar',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => -1
   
]);
```

Comment: Maybe you are not clear my requirement,  I need all posts from ```webinar``` post type and those posts from ```post``` post type that have category id ```43```

Comment: You should use 'relation' => 'OR  .  Like this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104060/using-or-conditions-in-meta-query-for-query-posts-argument

Answer (score -1):

```
$post_data = get_posts( [
    'post_type' => ['webinar', 'post'],
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
       'taxonomy' => 'category',
       'field'    => 'term_id',
       'terms'    => '43'
     ),
] );
```

Would something like this work? I have not tested this so may need playing with a bit.

If you dont want to use get_posts then can always use new WP_Query but will need to ammend

Comment: I guess my second code example and your one exact same thing.

Comment: They are similar but this one should work for you